# Chose what to move and what not to move when synchronizing clips

Tags: premiere

In Premiere Pro, is it possible to choose which clips move and which is the one that stays put when synchronizing them?

The audio seems to be moved to match one of the videos, and I need the audio to stay put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I achieved this. When synchronizing, clips are never moved to the left, so I achieved by putting the audio that I wanted to keep still to the right of all the clips that I'm synchronizing to it. I also select it first, just in case.